# How do I get color changes to take effect over the entire app for iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uicolor

I have a sort of test app where I'm auditioning various color schemes. The app makes use of global color variables called `myHighlight` and `mySecondaryColor`. I have an array of colors I would like to audition. I have a button that when pressed changes those variables to the next colors I want to test, but how do I get all of my views that use them to reload and use the new values? Calling `setNeedsDisplay()` does not work, I'm assuming because the views have already stored their background colors as instance properties and no longer use the global reference. Is there a way to clear the memory and get all views to re-initialize so I can see the results of the color change without re-starting the app?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28648406/7616030 would help I guess

Comment: I am going to vote to close as the question feels very broad (what specifically do you want to update a whole view, a label, a table view, other items?) and will attract opinion based answers rather than clear cut answer in it's currently posed format. To make your question a little clearer consider adding what questions or resources you've tried to find, code you currently are using and anything other more specific to your issue that makes the question clearer and less broad.

Comment: What I want to update is everything. Every view in the view controller. All at once. Essentially re-loading the view controller from scratch without having to force-quit the app and re-start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment in response to my comment, since you want to update every view in the app, and with the limited information you have provided regarding your existing architecture, and taking into consideration that your app is for testing purposes, here is my recommended **simplest** solution.

For consistency and ensuring your theme is applied completely, dismissing and re-presenting the view controller is the simplest option for demonstrating a theme change, and, this approach avoids the need to quit the app and reload.

I would have a UIViewController that is used as Launch View, which you can call when you make the colour theme changes (or any other UI changes requiring a full refresh) to present to and then back to your original View Controller.

Let's picture your architecture like so:

[image: Simple App Theme Architecture]

***VC-1*** is what appears briefly on launch before presenting to ***VC-2***. In your `viewDidAppear` method, you could have a *dispatch after "n" seconds* that then presents (or `show`, but probably best to use `present`) ***VC-2***.

Any time you update your theme, which can be colors, fonts and icons, you could then `dismiss` ***VC-2*** and `present` ***VC-1*** again, which will then re-present a new instance of ***VC-2*** with your colour choice after that `n` amount of time in the *dispatch after* call in the `viewDidAppear`.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than accessing each view after button/switch is pressed how about using `NotificationCenter`? Here is a solution that might work for you:

1. Create a custom `Notification.Name` let's call it `AppThemeChanged`
2. Subscribe to this notification from views which you'd like to change colors of by
   `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appThemeChanged), name: Notification.Name.AppThemeChanged, object: nil)`
3. In `appThemeChanged` function reset the colors
4. When the button is pressed notify the views
   `NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name.AppThemeChanged, object: nil, userInfo: nil)`

Also I'd suggest storing selected theme in a share instance or somewhere globally accessible.

Example:

```
class MyView: UIView {

    // Could be any initialize function which is called from your views
    // awakeFromNib(), init(frame: CGRect), init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) etc.
    func initialize() {
        if ThemeManager.shared.theme == .dark {
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.myBGColorDark
        } else {
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.myBGColorLight
        } 

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appThemeChanged), name: Notification.Name.Theme.AppThemeChanged, object: nil)
    }

    @objc func appThemeChanged() {
        if ThemeManager.shared.theme == .dark {
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.myBGColorDark
        } else {
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.myBGColorLight
        } 
    }
}
```